# Trying to hide logo from task bar

Tags: hide

Does anyone know how to hide a running logo from small icon tray and task bar.  What application should I try to do this? I have tried couple of applications for this, but they were not successful .

Comment: Can you share with us the specific things you have tried? Also, please note that asking for a software tool to fix a problem is specifically off topic on this site. Instead, just ask us how to fix the problem and don't ask for a software solution. Finally, the term "logo" may be off putting to some here. That is an icon, and while it may be a logo, on your computer it isn't a "logo" it's an "icon" and it indicates a program with that icon is running. As you're editing your post, changing the term "logo" to "icon" will likely help your question make more sense here.

Comment: Rather than reposting an identical question please [edit your previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1835940/how-to-hide-running-logo-in-the-task-bar) to provide more details so that we can actually answer it. What is a "running logo"? What are you actually trying to do? Screenshots might be useful to describe what you need to do.

Comment: Running logo means when an app is open and in use. I'm trying to hide the AMMYY admin logo while the app is still running in the background. I don't want the AMMYY Admin logo to show in the task bar or icon tray. I tried to hide the logo through the task manager, but it didn't work. Is there any app or another way I can hide this logo?